# Cannot retrieve Shrine metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5.2, shrine

I am switching from Paperclip to Shrine because of Paperclip deprecation.

In my model `Profilepic.rb` file I used to retrieve dimensions of an image variant as follow:

```
before_create  :save_ratio    

def save_ratio
    geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original])
    self.ratio = geo.width / geo.height
  end
```

Basically I am saving the vertical ratio of an image.

It was working well with Paperclip : I grabbed the temporary image `queued_for_write` and checked dimensions with `Paperclip::Geometry` before saving the value.

In Shrine I have added the following to the uploader :

```
plugin :add_metadata
plugin :store_dimensions
```

It works great as I have all information available and images are uploaded to S3 properly.

Yet my new method for saving the image ratio no longer works :

```
after_create  :save_ratio
def save_ratio
    self.ratio = self.image[:original].width.to_i / self.image[:original].height.to_i
  end
```

I get

> error undefined method `[]' for
>   ProfilepicUploader::UploadedFile:0x00007f69a685c750>

Whereas, in console, after image has been created :

```
Profilepic.first.image[:original].width.to_i
```

does return the correct value.

EDIT

My uploader :

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ProfilepicUploader < Shrine
    include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
    plugin :processing
    plugin :validation_helpers # to validate image data
    plugin :versions
    plugin :add_metadata
    plugin :store_dimensions

    Attacher.validate do
        validate_max_size 5.megabyte
        validate_mime_type_inclusion ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']
    end

    process(:store) do |io, context|
        versions = { original: io } # retain original

        io.download do |original|
            pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)

            versions[:editable]  = pipeline.resize_to_fit!(700, 700)
            versions[:thumbnail] = pipeline.resize_to_fill!(400, 400)
            versions[:small]  = pipeline.resize_to_fill!(200, 200)
        end

        versions # return the hash of processed files
    end

end
```

my model :

```
class Profilepic < ApplicationRecord
  require "image_processing/mini_magick"
  belongs_to :professionnel
  before_create :set_hashid

  include ProfilepicUploader::Attachment.new(:image) # adds an `image` virtual attribute
  include ProfilepicFinalUploader::Attachment.new(:final_image) # adds an `image` virtual attribute


 attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h   

 after_create  :save_ratio_image   

private

  def save_ratio
    self.ratio = self.image[:original].width.to_i / self.image[:original].height.to_i
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrine first saves the record with the cached file, then again with the stored processed files. The reason you're getting the error is because your code is first being run when cached file is being assigned, at which point no processing has yet been done, and `self.image` is a single uploaded file (not a Hash of uploaded files).

What you probably want is extract the ratio already from the *cached* file (which is the same uploaded file as the `:original` after processing):

```
def save_ratio
  if image_data_changed? && image_attacher.cached?
    self.ratio = image.width.to_f / image.height.to_f
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can create `image_width` and `image_height` columns and have Shrine automatically populate them with `width` & `height` metadata, then calculate the ration later in SQL.

```
class ProfilepicUploader < Shrine
  plugin :metadata_attributes, width: :width, height: height
end
```

As mentioned in the other answer's comments, you can also use a JSONB column for the attachment column, which allows you to fetch the `width` & `height` metadata with SQL as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I did the calculation in the view, and not in the model as I wasn't sure what was available in the model when the record was created (Json was obviously not ready yet). The view can be accessed only when the image is ready... which fixes the pb.  Also Andre answer to grab context in uploader is probably correct (I got wrong ratio because of `to_i` instead of `to_f`) but I prefer to keep uploaders data and model data in their respective scope..

Comment: Actually I have implemented your solution from the cached file. It works perfectly. thks

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents:

If you are using Shrine::Attach.promote to process files in background, through a job or worker and the `versions` metadata may will not be available at that time (after_create callback time).

I'm not sure what's the best way to solve this, but you may access the model in processing phase through the context (https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/v2.16.0/doc/processing.md#processing-on-upload):

```rb
class SomeUploader < Shrine
  process(:store) do |io, context|
    ratio = io.metadata["width"] / io.metadata["height"]
    model = context[:record]
    model.update(ratio: ratio)

    versions = { original: io } # retain original
    io.download do |original|
      pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
      versions[:small]  = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(300, 300)
      # ....
    end
    versions
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I will try your solution. At the moment I try to implement this is the model. Maybe doing it from the uploader will work. It is hard to understand the scope of Uploader vs actual model with Shrine. I will try to find a resource going through the actual process and path of the image across the rails app, S3, the uploader ..

Comment: Actually your link quit explains this. I will try to go thruugh it in depth.

Comment: You can still access the width and height in that callback through the image_data attribute

Comment: I just tried to do a Json.parse : `JSON.parse(Profilepic.first.image_data)["original"]["metadata"]["width"].to_i` does work in the console after the first profilepic has been created. Though `self.ratio = JSON.parse(self.image_data)["original"]["metadata"]["width"].to_i / JSON.parse(self.image_data)["original"]["metadata"]["height"].to_i` sends the same error. Like nothing can be accessed `after_create` in the model .. :/ I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Your solution of updating the ration from the uploader returns no error, yet the field is always populated with `0`. But I am not doing the upload and processing async .. very strange. I will go on working on this ..

Comment: I never needed to parse the JSON contents, I don't know about your model but if created a JSON / JSONB column (In postgreSQL) the hash is already serialized in your model; Remember that (1/2 ==0) in ruby; you may need to convert to a float to fit your needs

Comment: Oh ok, actually I made it a text column as per Shrine quickstart guide https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine . I will make it a JSON column though. Regarding the ratio column, I have not touched it, it is a double precision and used to work fine with Paperclip. Also I have left Paperclip columns: `image_content_type` `image_file_size` though it should not really interfere .. I will delete them though, just to make sure it is not the pb

Comment: FYI, Shrine returns integers for width & height, so you need to convert them to a float before division.